# Getting the total from sub fields located in CPT

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to collect a series of numbers inside a repeatable subfield in a custom post type, and then output the sum in a line of text. I've written the code below, but I have been having very little success in getting it to work.

Would appreciate if someone could have a look and amend for my education. Thanks

```php
<?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'distribution-post' );
  $amount = new WP_Query( $args );
  $total = 0;

  while ( have_rows('arr_dist') ) : the_row();
      $total += intval( get_sub_field('amount'));
  endwhile;

  echo $total;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. you have missed using have_post before using have_row.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'distribution-post' );
  $amount = new WP_Query( $args );
  $total = 0;

  if ( $amount->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $amount->have_posts() ) : $amount->the_post(); 
            while ( have_rows('arr_dist') ) : the_row();
              $total += intval( get_sub_field('amount'));
            endwhile;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

  echo $total;
  wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
$total = 0;
while(the_repeater_field('repeaterfield name' )): 
         
$total += get_sub_field('repeatersubfield name' );
         
endwhile; 
echo $total;
?>
```

change repeater field and sub-field as per your need.